# RegEx for capturing specific alphanumeric pattern

Tags: regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy, uipath

I have this string and I want to know how extract the "10-K_20190304_29_1_20190515" part.

```
"nCABALLERO MARIA\r\n10.1-K\r\n10-K_20190304_29_1_20190515\r\n6204 DEPORTES SANTIAGO - PEÑALOLÉN"
```

I've tried this, `.+(?<=_).+`, but it brings me more characters that I need.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here, we like to start with a simple left and right boundary and collect our desire data and save it in a capturing group (`$1`). Let's start with:

```
[0-9]{2}-.+[0-9]{8}
```

and lets add our capturing group:

```
([0-9]{2}-.+[0-9]{8})
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jSY1YQ/1)

```js
const regex = /[0-9]{2}-.+[0-9]{8}/gm;
const str = `nCABALLERO MARIA\\r\\n10.1-K\\r\\n10-K_20190304_29_1_20190515\\r\\n6204 DEPORTES SANTIAGO - PEÑALOLÉN`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jSY1YQ/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If we wish to add more boundaries, we can certainly do so, depending on how our possible inputs might look like. For example, this expression has more boundaries:

```
([0-9]{2}-[A-Z]+_[0-9]{8}[0-9_]+.+?[0-9]{8})
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MIDDs6/1)

```js
const regex = /([0-9]{2}-[A-Z]+_[0-9]{8}[0-9_]+.+?[0-9]{8})/gm;
const str = `nCABALLERO MARIA\\r\\n10.1-K\\r\\n10-K_20190304_29_1_20190515\\r\\n6204 DEPORTES SANTIAGO - PEÑALOLÉN`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but in the full text there's more numbers and it doesn't recognise how I need it. Thats why I've match it with a _ because it only appears in the code. Please if you know how cut the entire code matching by _ it would be amazing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hope this helps someone else. I resolved by my own; When it brings to me: "15317029-0_20190102_29_1_20190515\r", I just: strCodigoPdf = strCodigoPdf.Substring(0,strCodigoPdf.Length()-0).Trim

Answer (score 0):

You can also use split to extract the "10-K_20190304_29_1_20190515" part.

```
text.Split({“\r\n”},StringSplitOptions.None)(2)
```

[image]